# how to use GUID in oData query and parse JSON as well

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest, dynamics-crm-2011, odata, dynamics-crm-online

I try to figure out how to deal with Odata query and XMLhttprequet in dynamics CRM
However, whatever I tried to do, eventially hasn't been working.

So, the trouble is how to send a oDAta query with GUID by creating a XMLhttprequest.
I checked that from lookup in the next code GUID gof record gets as well.

Also, I noticed that oData query works well too, I think it because I have some issue by dealing  with JSON. I wonder, does it work sinchronically in my way? 
Eventially, I'd like to parse a responseText in order to get a "new_address1" variable.

actually this code works fine if I change GUID on a text data of a  lookup, but it's not the best solution cos sometimes it duplicates

Did anyone use a GUID in a oData queries?

thanks in advance

```
 function test() 
   {
 //take a value from lookup
 var lookupItem = new Array(); 
  lookupItem = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("custom").getValue();
    var name = lookupItem[0].id; 

   var oDataPath =  "http://`ServerName`/`Organization`/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet(guid'" + name + "')";
 var retrieveRecordsReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  retrieveRecordsReq.open("GET", oDataPath, true);
  retrieveRecordsReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  retrieveRecordsReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

  retrieveRecordsReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (this.readyState == 4) {
   if (this.status == 200) {
      var retrievedRecords = JSON.parse(retrieveRecordsReq.responseText).d;
  var address = retrievedRecords.results[0].new_address1;
alert(address);        
   }
}
};
     retrieveRecordsReq.send();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OData Query Designer](https://crm2011odatatool.codeplex.com/) and [XrmServiceToolkit](https://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/) are two excellent, freely available resources out there to do the heavy lifting for you.

A bit of google research with the above and you should get further than you have.

Comment: I used to deal with the first one, however, haven't tried the second. I'll check.